# Extract value only of an XML field using xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

I'm trying to extract the value of a specific field in an XML file and got as far as:

```
xmllint --xpath '//component[@name="target_component"]/@team' my_file.xml
```

Which will return, say:

```
team="team_abc"
```

Is there a way to get the actual value, ie team_abc?
I've worked around this by using:

```
xmllint --xpath '//component[@name="target_component"]/@team' my_file.xml | awk '{ sub(/.*team=\"/, ""); sub(/\".*/, ""); print }'
```

but this seems pretty clumsy to me

Ideally, I'd want something that also handles single quotes, not just double quotes

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short, representative sample of your xml?

Comment: `xmllint` returns attributes like that unfortunately. As an alternative: `echo "team='team_abc'" | cut -d '=' -f 2 | tr -d '"'"'"` will get the value and remove both types of quotes

Answer (score 0):

Xpath `string()` function can be used but it will return the first value in the node set.

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//component[@name="target_component"]/@team)" tmp.xml
team_abc
```

For more than one attribute, get the first 3 in the nodeset

```
for i in 1 2 3; do printf '%s\n' "xpath string((//App/@action)[$i])";done |\
xmllint --shell tmp.xml |\
sed -nre 's/Object is a string : (.*)/\1/p'
A
B
A
```

Raw output without `sed` command

```
/ > xpath string((//App/@action)[1])
Object is a string : A
/ > xpath string((//App/@action)[2])
Object is a string : B
/ > xpath string((//App/@action)[3])
Object is a string : A
/ >
```

Alternative to `sed`:  `...| gawk 'BEGIN{FS=" : "} $0 ~ /^Object/ { print $2 }'`